# is Sprite Kit unit conversion meter->points 1:1?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

What is the ratio between meters and points in sprite kit?
'Cause on the apple documentation it says that the speeds and accelerations are in meter/sec - meters/sec^2, but it doesn't give a conversion in points/sec etc..

I tried measuring the speed of an object either with apple's sprites velocity attribute, either doing manually the calculation of the points per second, and I came up at a ca 1:1 ratio, meaning 1m/s = 1point/s.

Now, can anyone confirm that? or am I completely wrong?

Here is the code I used for the calculation:

```
double dt = currentTime - previousTime;
previousTime = currentTime;

double x = ball.physicsBody.velocity.dx;
double y = ball.physicsBody.velocity.dy;
double mod = sqrt(x*x+y*y);

double x2 = (ball.position.x-previousPosition.x)/dt;
double y2 = (ball.position.y-previousPosition.y)/dt;
double mod2 = sqrt(x2*x2+y2*y2);

if (mod2!=0){totalSpeed = totalSpeed + mod2;
    j++;}
double mod3 = totalSpeed/j;
NSLog(@"Ball Speed: %.2f - %.2f - %.2f",mod,mod2,mod3);
previousPosition = ball.position;
```

Comment: Assuming you wish to do this purely out of curiosity, I calculated it to be about 170 points / metre.

Comment: no, i needed it to set a speed of an object i'm dragging, cause i noticed that when i drag it it's velocity remains 0, with consequents problems on the collision physics, that don't accelerate the object it collides with but only act as a simple bounce...

Comment: Uh oh, what you are doing here is pre-solving your problem. Your original problem is the drag issue you're facing, and you assumed that a solution would arise from knowing about the points to metres ratio. Please post another question about the *original* issue you are facing.

Comment: ok, anyway why am i getting a total different result from yours?

Comment: That's not the way to do it. Also, that's not what you asked for. I think you're looking for the units the iOS physics world uses. As the docs say, all units are SI units.

Comment: Why do you care about metres though? Unless you are converting to real world location (some sort of AR stuff maybe). Without that then all distances are completely arbitrary. Deal in pixels or points. That's all that exists in the problem space you are working in. Creating a new unit is not going to help.

Comment: but isn't it that by doing a difference on the position i'm obtaining a difference in length? cause i know that velocity gives me an si unit, as of apple documentation, but .position.y should give me units as points, not meters, shouldn't he?

Comment: it's apple that cares about meters, not me; as specified in the documentation the speeds and accelerations are in meters

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/velocity

Comment: velocity
The physics body’s velocity vector, measured in meters per second.

@property(nonatomic) CGVector velocity
Availability
Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
Declared In
SKPhysicsBody.h

Comment: Well... that's bizarre. Can't understand why they would do that. lol.

Comment: @Frankie94 Hmm... I think you're looking for this... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW34 OK, that doesn't go to the correct section. Anyway, right at the bottom, "Fudging the numbers".

Comment: nor do i, cause it would really be easier if it was only with points... or if the ratio was a 1:1, but as duci9y found otherwise, and there is nothing official from apple i have no idea who is right...

Comment: yep, i read that, but as i have one unit coming from a function that gives me meter/sec, and another that theoretically should be points/sec, i was trying to be sure not to sum "apples with potatoes".